# Burninate request - 'guidelines'

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

[guidelines](/questions/tagged/guidelines) doesn't seems to be a meaning-full tag and should be deleted. This is currently having 312 questions.

Let me know your suggestions.

Comment: While it initially seems a bit meta, it does seem to be legitimately used on questions regarding Apple or facebook guidelines. It might actually have some uses.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that anyone would want to follow the [guidelines](/questions/tagged/guidelines) tag or search on it, though more specific variations on it (e.g., on style guidelines for Java programming) would be useful. It should go, but the questions should be reviewed for whether there are sufficient exact-enough tags on them already, or whether those tags should be created.

For example, using recently asked questions in the tag, [Correct directory for downloadable content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15108287/301832) and [iOS Data Storage Guidelines after add NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15405100/301832) probably ought to have a tag relating to “iOS Data Storage guidelines” whereas https://stackoverflow.com/q/15405455/301832 can probably just lose the tag without losing search-ability or relevance.